# Rails Pundit access to the params or object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I've got two models - `Physician` and `Patient`. Physician can only give recommendations to patients who have completed the phone number on their account, otherwise the physician should be redirected to the edit patient page. Below is my code:

recommendation_controller.rb new method

```
  def new
    authorize Recommendation
    @registrant = Registrant.find(params[:registrant_id])
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new(patient: @registrant)
  end
```

policies

```
class RecommendationPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def new?
    login.physician?
  end
end


class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :login, :record

  def initialize(login, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless login
    @login = login
    @record = record
  end
end
```

So the question is how to pass @registrant object in to the `new?` policy to check if that registrant has a phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will create custom permission under `RegistrantPolicy` to check recommendation allowed or not.

policy:

```
class RegistrantPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def recommendation_allowed?
    record.phone_number.present?
  end
end
```

and apply it in `recommendation_controller.rb` like

```
  def new
    authorize Recommendation
    @registrant = Registrant.find(params[:registrant_id])
    authorize @registrant, :recommendation_allowed?
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new(patient: @registrant)
  end
```